# How can I identify all the tables that get written to, when some application code gets executed?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to find out the tables that are being touched when some piece of .net code is executed. How can I do that? There may be quite a few tables that get written to in one transaction and it would be helpful to get some sort of listing of all those that get affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sql Server you have a tool called Profiler (not in the express versions though). Go to Management Studio, Tools menu, there should be "Sql Profiler". It's running as a separate application.

When stared, you provide it with a connection to the database server you want to monitor. There's all kinds of things you can monitor, but most probably you'll just want to filter the database and see the queries:

- Go to Event Selection
- Check the "Show all columns"
- Open "Column filters"
- Enter your database name in the filter list, and anything else you might be interested in (most usually, the defaults works just fine)

Now, when you click "Run" the trace is running. Pause it, run your code to the line where you want to see what's happening and then unpause. You'll see all the queries that get executed (not just by your code, but anything that gets executed against db).

You didn't specify what version of sql server you're using, but the profiler is there since v2000, with maybe minor differences.

Comment: +1 this is the way I do it, then I just filter on what I need to capture!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework, you can ask the ChangeTracker property of your DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSet<...> stuff excluded in this sample

    public override SaveChanges()
    {
        var changes = ChangeTracker.Entries;

        // changes now contains every piece that has been touched in this DbContext before saving
    }
}
```